# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 decryption in Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptojs

I'm a Noob to Java and Javascript. I'm trying to decrypt a Java encrypted text using Javascript, tried with both CryptoJS and node-forge, but the decrypted text I'm getting is gibberish.

Java cipher creation (this works in JAVA where we pass in the ciphermode as Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE and is able to decrypt the line encrypted using the same cipher algo/spec)

```
Cipher c;
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterationsCount, bitStrength));
SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(cipherMode, keyspec);
return c;
```

Anyone know of a good Js library that I can use or provide some sample of how to decrypt the encrypted line using this Cipher and KeySpec?

Javascript Code

```
const bufferStr = Buffer.from(encryptedStr, "base64"); //encryptedStr is the encrypted string in base64 format

//generate key using node forge
//password is a String, salt is a hex, numIterations is an int
const AESkey = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(password, salt, numIterations, 32);

var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher("AES-ECB", AESkey);
decipher.start({});
//console.log(decipher);
decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(bufferStr));
var result = decipher.finish(); // check 'result' for true/false
// outputs decrypted hex
console.log(decipher.output);
```

Output

```
ByteStringBuffer {
  data:
   'ÏWÊƒÓYqŽé\u0017\u0000†\u0018ŸHª3•—²Ì[iòjóÑ8⌂\u0002k\rÒ\r­\u0018EvX!ØçQâ!1zåDÉ-<\u0012s)‰²\u001aò=k6<å`r’Ã×lCê)Xq×mÊ¥ ‚Ø\u0000D°lë¶³È\b>‘`eó¾Î<å\u001c•g|K\\Ù\u0014\u0010@œó\u0019±žk¯þM“‹¾tüzØçBïõîi¸\u0006ÙZ9Jsæ!kµ¸Ã.à-É‹Ï69',
  read: 0,
  _constructedStringLength: 208 }
```

Additional Details

On the Java Side

```
String password = <Password String>;
byte[] salt = { bytes array|| String };
int iterationCount = 65536;
int bitStrength = 256;

encryptedText = <base64 encoded string>'; //this is what I'm trying to decrypt
```

Node JS Code I'm using to decrypt this (and I'm doing something really wrong :( )

```
const forge = require('node-forge');    
const password = <password as String>;
    const salt = new Int8Array(new Buffer(<array of bytes>)); //converting from Java byte[] array
    const numIterations = 65536;
    const keyPhrase = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(password, salt, numIterations, 32, "SHA512");

    const encryptedText =
        "<base64 encoded String>";

    let decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher("AES-ECB", keyPhrase);
    decipher.start({});

    decipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(encryptedText));
    let result = decipher.finish(); // check 'result' for true/false

    console.log(decipher.output);
    //Outputs a ByteStringBuffer
    /*ByteStringBuffer {
      data:
       'ÜB\rÌ9pÞ[\u000e²&øV$²ÝªüÚf\u0000ÀÅmè·èjÉû¤Á|ê¹õIpð\u0012ì\u001cª\f\u000f¦¹ñøÄ\u001b!ëáÕXô\u0007½¦{±\u0012\u001a®}@U6òöÞÊ\u0016n§@gf h£xû\u0016jyÕ5Õ3ÍJ&\n^Eå2õÉ\u000eÑßü!ªÎâÉ\u0010!eÑ.&·à\u0011¬\u0005\u0015/#&\u0019&Wà­ÃK\u000eç8|\'Ê­b°¸ó¹Ñ\bS\u0004lÑ´<\u0011O½\u0014q?uu$\u001c\b^»',
      read: 0,
      _constructedStringLength: 192 }*/
```

Comment: In the _forge_ code, the digest must be specified in the 5th parameter of `forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2`, which must be `SHA512` with regard to the Java code. Otherwise the default `SHA1` is used.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco Tried that but still the same result.

Comment: However, it works for me with this change ;-) You should post a concrete **_test_** example: password, salt, iteration count, plaintext, Base64 encoded ciphertext, which would make the analysis easier.

Comment: plain text that's encrypted is '2019-10-18 12:47:54,343|INFO |USBHelper                     |USB-Keyboard-1                |Processing USB data: 00,A1,FF,04,02,08,00,01,32,' Other details added to the original quesiton. Thank you again @Topaco

Comment: Works for me. I suggest you edit your question and _add_ a section where you post the _modified_ NodeJS code you are currently using. By the way, the plaintext contains spaces and control characters: `2019-10-18 12:47:54,343|INFO |USBHelper<21 blanks>|USB-Keyboard-1<16 blanks>|Processing USB data: 00,A1,FF,04,02,08,00,01,32,\r\n`

Comment: @Topaco I must be doing something terribly wrong with the types. have updated the original post with the nodejs code I'm using. Would love to hear your thoughts.. Also, would there be any issues with decrypting plaintext with spaces and control characters. I would assume those will also be encrypted during the JAVA encryption process?

Comment: Replace `encryptedText` in `createBuffer` with `Buffer.from(encryptedText, 'base64')`. This should fix the problem. Also, the salt is easier to write: `const salt = Buffer.from([106, 117, 115, 116, 115, 111, 109, 101]);` whereby the current expression doesn't cause an error. During encryption, binary data are processed; whether these represent printable characters, control characters, or blanks is irrelevant. I just wanted to point out that the plaintext you posted does not match the decrypted one (at least not exactly).

Comment: Thank you so much @Topaco Works like a charm. Appreciate it.